# Filter Drive is not loaded - Startup

Tags: ndis, filter-driver

I have configured my filter driver start type as SERVICE_SYSTEM_START in .inf file, Installed the filter driver manually using the instructions on the Light weight filter driver sample, rebooted the virtual machine to know if my driver is loaded. in the ntbtlog.txt which has all the driver information it says "Did not load driver ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista x64 platform, All the drivers that are not signed will not be loaded by the Windows, So that was the reason for Not loading Driver. To fix this I have used "Disable Signature Enforcement" option in the Boot menu by pressing F8 during the boot. This would disable the restriction while development of the driver.